# Break newcommand arguments by '/' for different use?

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm creating a presentation with a lot of frames with one figure per slide. So instead of having hundreds of the same code over and over again I created a simple `\newcommand` for it where one of the argument is the figure-name which I also use as the label for the figure. But when I use figure subfolders the argument is: `subfolderone/subfoldertwo/figurename`. But I only want to use `figurename` as the figure label.

Is it possible to break the #1 argument by "/" and use only the last one for labeling? Else... I'll just make another input argument.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\figcaptiontitlecrop}[7]{%
    \begin{frame}[b]{#3}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[trim=#4mm #5mm #6mm #7mm, clip]{#1}
            \caption{#2}%
            \label{fig:#1}%
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\figcaptiontitlecrop{filename}{Caption Text}{Frame Title Here}{0}{0}{0}{0}
%\figcaptiontitlecrop{figures/subfolder/filename}{Caption Text}{Frame Title Here}{0}{0}{0}{0}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `SplitList` from `xparse` could help or a key-value interface. A user command with 7 arguments is error-prone!

Comment: Since #4-#7 are trim arguments, it may be easier to just collapse that into a single `{0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm}` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A command with seven arguments should be avoided. A key-value approach is better:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\beamerfigure}{mm}
 {
  \begin{frame}[b]
  \keys_set:nn { bjartmar/beamerfigure } { #1 }
  \frametitle{\l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_title_tl}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:N \includegraphics [
        \l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_options_tl,
        trim=\l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_tl,
        clip
      ]
    }{\l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_path_tl / \l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_name_tl}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{fig:\l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_name_tl}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
}
\keys_define:nn { bjartmar/beamerfigure }
 {
  title   .tl_set:N  = \l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_title_tl,
  path    .tl_set:N  = \l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_path_tl,
  path    .initial:n = {.},
  name    .tl_set:N  = \l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_name_tl,
  options .tl_set:N  = \l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_options_tl,
  trim    .tl_set:N  = \l_bjartmar_beamerfigure_tl,
  trim    .initial:n = 0~0~0~0,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\beamerfigure{
  name=donald-duck,
  options={height=.5\textheight},
  trim=0 5 0 5,
}{This is Donald Duck}

\beamerfigure{
  path=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/,
  name=example-grid-100x100pt,
}{Another figure}

\end{document}
```

If no `path` is specified, the current directory is used. As you see, you can also specify additional options for `\includegraphics`.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Happy to learn something new. I'll defiantly use  this and the method in the future! I don't know why, but I had to move `\keys_set:nn { bjartmar/beamerfigure } { #1 }` outside the frame environment to make the frametitle to work.

Comment: @bjartmar Strange. But in that case, add also `\group_begin:` at the start and `\group_end:` at the end, or the variables would be clobbered. You're not using the deprecated syntax `\begin{frame}{frame title}`, are you?